# How to schedule an Oracle dbms_scheduler Job timezone and DST safely

Tags: oracle11g, timezone, dst, job-scheduling, dbms-scheduler

I am trying to setup a DBMS_SCHEDULER Job to run exactly at 1 AM on 1st of January every year on Oracle 11g. How to setup its attributes to be absolutely sure it wont get executed in wrong hour, because of timezone differences nor Daylight Savings Time.

I have spent plenty of time going through Oracle documentation, but I have still not reached the level of certainity.

Just btw, here are the rules which I found and consider relevant to the subject:

**Job attributes**

**start_date**  This attribute specifies the first date on which this job is scheduled to start. If start_date and repeat_interval are left null, then the job is scheduled to run as soon as the job is enabled.
For repeating jobs that use a calendaring expression to specify the repeat interval, start_date is used as a reference date. The first time the job will be scheduled to run is the first match of the calendaring expression that is on or after the current date.
The Scheduler cannot guarantee that a job will execute on an exact time because the system may be overloaded and thus resources unavailable.

**repeat_interval** This attribute specifies how often the job should repeat. You can specify the repeat interval by using calendaring or PL/SQL expressions.
The expression specified is evaluated to determine the next time the job should run. If repeat_interval is not specified, the job will run only once at the specified start date. See "Calendaring Syntax" for further information.

**Rules in Calendaring syntax**

- The calendaring syntax does not allow you to specify a time zone.
  Instead the Scheduler retrieves the time zone from the start_date
  argument. If jobs must follow daylight savings adjustments you must
  make sure that you specify a region name for the time zone of the
  start_date. For example specifying the start_date time zone as
  'US/Eastern' in New York will make sure that daylight saving
  adjustments are automatically applied. If instead the time zone of
  the start_date is set to an absolute offset, such as '-5:00',
  daylight savings adjustments are not followed and your job execution
  will be off by an hour half of the year.
- When start_date is NULL, the Scheduler will determine the time zone for the repeat interval as follows:
- It will check whether the session time zone is a region name. The session time zone can be set by either:
  Issuing an ALTER SESSION statement, for example: SQL> ALTER SESSION
  SET time_zone = 'Asia/Shanghai'; Setting the ORA_SDTZ environment
  variable.
- If the session time zone is an absolute offset instead of a region name, the Scheduler will use the value of the DEFAULT_TIMEZONE Scheduler attribute. For more information, see the SET_SCHEDULER_ATTRIBUTE Procedure.
- If the DEFAULT_TIMEZONE attribute is NULL, the Scheduler will use the time zone of systimestamp when the job or window is enabled.

Comment: wouldn't you just schedule for 01/01/20xx 01:00 in the local "clock" time of the database server?  Did you try running a test?

Comment: To be honest, this is too vague for me. What do you mean by scheduling in local clock? How should the attributes be set like?
And no, I didn't made much testing yet, since I find it a bit too complicated to test Time Zone changes, DST changes and still not have the certainty that it is correct.

Comment: @OldProgrammer:  Unfortunately doing that doesn't consider [DST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time).  Oracle will schedule your job for a non-DST time, which if you are in DST won't be the time you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am unsure if this answer truly passes the rules of an answer on this site, but after spending a lot of time googling I came up with the following solution:

```
start_date      => CAST(trunc(sysdate, 'YEAR')+2/24 AS TIMESTAMP) at time zone 'Europe/Berlin'
```

I believe this is closest to safest solution because:

- It uses timestamp instead of date - i believe it forces the job to be truly executed on given time in given timezone, while ignoring DMBS_SCHEDULER default_timezone. I found also some suggestions that say that it is also unsafe to use directly timestamp, that only this cast is safe
- I selected manually the timezone I need, with the hope, that it would not come to conflict with local settings. Altough it is unclear to me, whether it is now truly unrelated to SESSIONTIMEZONE, or DBTIMEZONE and whether it affects the proper time of run.
- I have used a little hack, even though the request is that the job should start after midnight, I have set it to 2AM, with the hope that even in case of bad time zone and bad daylight savings it would get moved max +-2 hours.

I would be happier with the solution, if I would be absolutely clear on when the job actually gets executed with the respect of local time of a server, SESSIONTIMEZONE, DBTIMEZONE, start_date Time Zone and a DBMS_SCHEDULER time zone.

I am also unhappy with the Time Zone specification, since its has 4 abbreviations linked with it - LMT, CET, CEST, CEMT, where CEST seems to me like being completely wrong. My target is to use CET with Daylight savings(winter!=summer).

Answer (score 2):

You may use this to make sure you pass a timestamp with time zone and that the start date will have a timezone name (US/Eastern) instead of an offset (ex: +5:00). This way, as the above fragments from the oracle docs mention, the Scheduler will keep track of DST.

-- Create a SCHEDULE

```
declare 
 v_start_date timestamp with time zone;
BEGIN 

select localtimestamp at time zone 'US/Eastern' into v_start_date from dual; --US/Eastern

DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_SCHEDULE(
      schedule_name => 'SAMPLE_SCHEDULE',
      start_date => v_start_date,
      repeat_interval => 'FREQ=DAILY; BYHOUR=10; BYMINUTE= 15',
      comments => 'Runs daily at the specified hour.'); 
END;
```

To make sure you have set it properly you can run this: 
ALTER SESSION SET nls_timestamp_tz_format = 'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS tzr tzd';

Now, create two schedules, one as above and one using sysdate as the start_date parameter and execute the query below.

```
-- Check the TIMEZONE 
select * from USER_SCHEDULER_SCHEDULES;


v1:
27-MAR-14 11.44.24.929282 AM **US/EASTERN**

v2:

27-MAR-14 05.44.54.000000 PM **+05:00**
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually I have never tried it with `.CREATE_SCHEDULE` method but `.CREATE_JOB` has also start_date parameter and what works for me is just plain

```
start_date => TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('00:10 Europe/Rome','hh24:mi tzr'
```

It retains 'Europe/Rome' when I query dba_scheduler_jobs:

```
SELECT job_name, TO_CHAR(start_date) start_date,
                 TO_CHAR(next_run_date) next_run_date
    FROM dba_scheduler_jobs;
```

Answer (score 0):

To add a bit more info to this, when you want to check if modification was successful.
Run query: select * from all_scheduler_jobs where owner='schema_name'.
There you can see in the field start_date, which has type timestamp with timezone, that it contains data like: 2017-12-05 01:55:00,000000000 EUROPE/YOUR_CITY
Having time zone info at the end confirms that it is properly saved for the job.
Then, also, next_run_date is aligned with start_date and it should also show time zone details.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT DBMS_SCHEDULER.STIME FROM DUAL;
```

[Reference](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_daylight_savings_time_and_dbms_scheduler.htm)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).